# Laravel access denied but I can connect using phpmyadmin or normal php query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm getting this error message when I try to migrate using artisan

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'myuser'@'mycomputerip'
(using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where t
able_schema = database and table_name = migrations)


[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'myuser'@'mycomputerip'
(using password: YES)
```

I have tryed to use my local xampp mysql database and that did also not work.

I'm using mariadb on the server which is the one I'm trying to connect to.

env file (default chagnes bcus security)

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=serverip
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=myuser
DB_PASSWORD=mysecurepassword
```

I am able to connect using a normal php mysqli connection or with phpmyadmin

Comment: app/config/databese.php ... check this

Comment: you have not create user, you probably only have `'myuser'@'localhost'`user defined, but to do this you would also need `'myuser'@'my_ip_address'` or `'myuser'@'%'` (for "every address").

Comment: @tereško  env file (default chagnes bcus security) ... he mention there due to..security

Comment: http://tutsnare.com/access-denied-for-user-homesteadlocalhost-laravel-5/ ... Try THis ..

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar Have tryed that.

Answer (score 0):

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=myuser
DB_PASSWORD='' or DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

And

```
php artisan config:clear
```

**and Then Restart Your serve and Then Try it..**

Comment: the database isent local, I only have a xampp localy and that also dident work.